# Mozilla Firefox extension for night reading?

Tags: firefox, reading, dark-theme

I'm looking for an extension for Mozilla Firefox that functions just like [Dark Reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) for Google Chrome.

> [Dark Reader] uses special intellectual way to transform bright blinding stuff into eye relaxing, high contrast, deluminated, dark themed and just smart looking web-pages which are easy to read at night

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may also want to try [Owl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/owl/), a light add-on built specifically for this purpose, and very much Dark Reader for Chrome.

(Disclaimer: I also happen to be the developer of this [and [other](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/user/Sidhant/)] add-ons)

Comment: Works great on some sites... doesn't work so well with others (e.g., on my computer, this page is a solid blank gray screen when Owl is activated).

Comment: @dat you may want to try the Classic theme from the dropdown panel, it works on sites where the other theme doesn't. Thanks for using Owl :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Stylish (FF)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) --- [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en) and install user styles built for darkness. I'm personally using a few 'skins' on Firefox and Pale Moon. Some sites are a bit buggy and require you to exclude sites from time to time.

https://userstyles.org/styles/browse/global?as=1&per_page=50&sort=updated_date&sort_direction=desc

I'm using [Black Web](https://userstyles.org/styles/78507/black-web) and [High Contrast](https://userstyles.org/styles/101643/high-contrast) and they work on every site I go to. You can even reskin browsers too.

Answer (score 3):

You can install [Dark Reader for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/darkreader/). It makes exact the same dark themes as [Dark Reader for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Two extension pops up when [searching](//google.com/search?q=dark+reader+firefox) and those are the extensions:

- [Blank your monitor easy readin](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/blank-your-monitor-easy-readin/) - Blank Your Monitor provide a simple mechanism to change Firefox color combination in order to invert the usage of white and black colors
- [Dark backgrounds switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/dark-backgrounds-switcher/) - Easily switch the color of foreground (text) to yellow/white and background to black. The plugin offers three modes: yellow on black, white on black and back to page's defaults. (Might be discontinued)

When I first read your posting, another program however came into my mind, and that is the [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) which changes the color of your computer according to time of day, reducing amongst other the blue intensity. Lifehacker has a more extensive article on similar topix of [How to Invert Your Browser Colors for Easier Reading at Night](http://lifehacker.com/5912480/how-to-invert-your-browsers-colors-for-easier-reading-at-night).

Comment: Did you use some of these extensions? If so, what are your experiences?

Comment: @AngeloFuchs I haven't used them, but have seen them recommended. I'm contemplating on installing the f.lux software as I want to use computer/tables late at night, but also want to avoid disturbing the sleep process, if possible.

Comment: Thank you for those suggestions. I just tried both extensions and unfortunately they do not work nearly as well as Dark Reader does for Google Chrome. I have asked the developer of Dark Reader if he has any plans to develop the same extension for Mozilla Firefox. I will simply have to use Chrome for reading and Firefox for all other uses. Also, I would love to upvote @holroy's answer, but I need two more points.

Answer (score 0):

i found [screen dimmer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screen-dimmer/)  addon  **for firefox** .

- This acts just like "deluminate" for chrome.
- You can access settings in right click menu.

**Description:** Darken any web page to reduce eye strain and increase comfort

**Features:**

- Change overlay color
- Increase, decrease or reset overlay with right mouse click or
  keyboard controls